# redirectToRoute Previous page on Symfony5

Tags: php, symfony, routes, controller, cart

I have a cart functionnality on my website.
I display the cart on two different page (cart.html.twig and home.html.twig) and I can modify the cart on those 2 pages.
When I'm suppose to increment a product+1 with the button I'm redirected to A SINGLE ROUTE.
If the user **increment the product on the homepage I want to him to be redirected to the homepage**, and **if he increment the product on the cart page I want to him to be redirected to the cart page**, how im suppose to do this, I'm little bit lost.
**There is a way to redirect to the previous page ?**

There is the code :

```
class CartService {

protected $session;
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, ProductRepository $productRepository){
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function add(int $id){
    $cart = $this->session->get('cart', []);

    if(isset($cart[$id])){
        $cart[$id]++;
    } else {
        $cart[$id] = 1;
    }

    $this->session->set('cart', $cart);
}

public function remove(int $id) {
    $cart = $this->session->get('cart', []);

    if(isset($cart[$id])){
        if($cart[$id] > 1){
            $cart[$id]--;
        } else {
            unset($cart[$id]);
        }
    }

    $this->session->set('cart', $cart);
}

public function delete(int $id){
    $cart = $this->session->get('cart', []);

    if(isset($cart[$id])){
        unset($cart[$id]);
    }

    $this->session->set('cart', $cart);
}

public function getFullCart() : array{
    $cart = $this->session->get('cart', []);
    
    $cartWithData = [];

    foreach($cart as $id => $quantity){
        $cartWithData[] = [
            'product' => $this->productRepository->find($id),
            'quantity' => $quantity
        ];
    }

    return $cartWithData;
}

public function getTotal(): float{
    $total = 0;

    foreach($this->getFullCart() as $item){
        $total += $item['product']->getPrice() * $item['quantity'];
    }

    return $total;
}
```

}

THE CONTROLLER of cartpage:

```
class CartController extends AbstractController{

/**
 * @Route ("/cart", name = "cart")
 */
public function cart(CartService $cartservice){

    return $this->render(
        'users/cart.html.twig',
        [
            'items' => $cartservice->getFullCart(),
            'total' => $cartservice->getTotal()
        ]
    );
}

/**
 * @Route ("/cart/add/{id}", name = "add_cart")
 */
public function add($id, CartService $cartservice, Request $request){
    $cartservice->add($id);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}


/**
 * @Route ("/cart/remove/{id}", name="remove_cart")
 */
public function remove($id, CartService $cartservice){
    $cartservice->remove($id);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}


/**
 * @Route ("/cart/delete/{id}", name="delete_cart")
 */
public function delete($id, CartService $cartservice){
    $cartservice->delete($id);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

}

And I also display a part of the cart on my homepage, I display the price / name / quantity of the card, the controller of my homepage "HomeController.php":

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
*/
public function home(ProductRepository $productRepository, CategoryRepository $categoryRepository, CartService $cartService) : Response{
    $productRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class);
    $products = $productRepository->findAll();
    $categories = $categoryRepository->findAll();
    return $this->render(
        'users/home.html.twig',
        [
            'products' => $products,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'total' => $cartService->getTotal(),
            'items' => $cartService->getFullCart()
        ]
    );
}
```

I tried this on the function add in CartController.php

```
    /**
 * @Route ("/cart/add/{id}", name = "add_cart")
 */
public function add($id, CartService $cartservice, Request $request){
    $cartservice->add($id);

    $uri = $request->attributes->get("_route");
    return $this->redirectToRoute($uri);
}
```

but it doesnt work, it say to me "Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "add_cart"." and the product increment x30. I think the function loop on the route cart/add/{id}.

Comment: Are you sure you want to redirect to '$request->attributes->get("_route")' Because if you don't override the variable it's just a reference. It's the original page path where the form is, not the path you want to redirect to (home etc.)

Comment: I tried this because i don't know how to do, I think `$uri = $request->attributes->get("_route");` take the route cart/add/{id} and dont take the previous route and thats why its doesnt work

Comment: try this out : `$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        return new RedirectResponse($referer);` in your controller. Not in your service. Btw your service should return a response.

Comment: Thanks alot! Im suppose to do `return $this->session->set('cart', $cart);` for example in my function add ?

Comment: You can create a generic response or return a bool (faster). Just be sure that your returned value don't raise blocking error and can be managed in the fallback function (where you initially called your service)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE :

I just need to get the referer like this :

```
    /**
 * @Route ("/cart/add/{id}", name = "add_cart")
 */
public function add($id, CartService $cartservice, Request $request){
    $cartservice->add($id);

    $route = $request->headers->get('referer');

    return $this->redirect($route);
}
```

and i get redirect to the previous page

Comment: Yes you found it ;) try this out : $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');         return new RedirectResponse($referer); in your controller. Not in your service. Btw your service should return a response.

Answer (score 1):

in your controller

```
 /**
 * @Route ("/cart/add/{id}/{origin}", name = "add_cart")
   */
  public function add($id, $origin, CartService $cartservice, Request 
      $request){
     $cartservice->add($id);

     return $this->redirectToRoute($origin);

    }
```

in your twig home page

```
<a href="{{ path('add_cart', 
 {'id':product.id,'origin':app.request.attributes.get('_route')})}}" >

  add +
 </a>
```

do the same for the others pages that you want

you can get the current path in twig using

app.request.attributes.get('_route')

then you give it to your controller

and finaly you can use an if condition to redirect

Comment: I've tried this but doesnt work : 
`$uri = $request->attributes->get("_route");
        if($uri == 'homepage'){
            $route = 'homepage';
        } elseif($uri == 'cart'){
            $route = 'cart';
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute($route);`
It say the variable route is not defined

Comment: Yes because you don't have a else cause. If $route is not 'cart' or 'homepage' then it's not defined. @FlexRtg